# Game state gives black screen

Tags: java, android

I am working on a game for android and when I implemented the different game states from Lunar Lander and Jet Boy it gives me a black screen. Before I added them it would draw and run how I needed it to. How do I get the game states to work with my game program.

Thanks for any help or advice.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who might run into this problem you have to add the state functions inside of the class files that call the SurfaceView i.e.: LunarLander or JetBoy.